# Ansible is not installing via PIP

Tags: python, linux, pip, ansible, centos7

I was following the tutorial on Ansible docs but was unable to finish it:

```
$ python -m pip install --user ansible
```

Returns an error:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

While another guide installed it by using python-pip3 and then after running `pip3 install --user ansible` it was ready to go.

It finishes installation successfully, yet ansible is still not available:

> -bash: /usr/bin/ansible: No such file or directory

I have never worked with Python or PIP in the past and I don't understand what could go wrong in the process to start debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution to this but instead I went with the CentOS Epel repository also described in the Ansible docs and it works this way.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install ansible
```

Edit: Ok, so all I had to do is to add the following to .bashrc file.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your python version in the terminal with

```
$ which python
```

command and then this returns a path that contains python(probably this will return a path because almost all of Linux distro contains python). After that result, you could type

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

in the terminal, and then type

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

pip will be installed after these commands.

Comment: I actually did all this. and I had PIP installed. The issue is it wasn't configuring PATH for Ansible so it wasn't usable after installation.